# Best way to run Database access tasks, that return objects, in separate thread keeping UI responsive?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, data-access-layer, splash-screen

[Windows forms application & .NET 4.0]

I need to execute database access methods that return objects (either list of classes or simple classes).

Also i need to open forms that are responsive while main thread does initialization.

I need to run these on separate threads keeping the User Interface responsive and of course to be able to pass the results back to main thread for UI updates.

I have been reading books regarding the various ways for this.

I understand that my job can be done by:

- BackGroundWorker
- Thread Class
- Task Class

Which one i should dive into ?

Update: using the suggested Task class i am getting errot for cross thread safety using this:

```
private void BtnCheckClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var itm =   Task<JDEItemLotAvailability>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                             Dal.GetLotAvailabilityF41021(
                                                         txtLot.Text,
                                                         cmbMcu.SelectedItem.ToString(),
                                                         cmbLocn.SelectedItem.ToString())
                            );
       lblDescriptionValue.Text = itm.Result.Description;
       lblItemCodeValue.Text = itm.Result.Code;
       lblQuantityValue.Text = itm.Result.AvailableQuantity.ToString();
       LotFocus(true);
}
```

On the above exmaple i am getting the exception in cmbMcu control not the txtLot.

Comment: Anything stopping you from jumping to .net 4.5? async/await make working with tasks much cleaner.

Comment: I need to run on some old and maybe XP, this is my only barrier...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the **[`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx)** class, it's really easy to synchronize it and it already provides a support for returning objects.

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(
    () => GetDatabaseData(someArguments),
    TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

// Example method
public DataSet GetDatabaseData(object args) { ... }
```

this this tells a **[scheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997402.aspx)** to create and begin a new task and gives it a hint that it might be a good idea not to use a thread-pool thread, if the scheduler uses a thread-pool. Anyway you can now decide how do you want to synchronize.

For example to achieve similar behaviour as in Gregor Primar's answer, you can set up a continuation using **[`ContinueWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696.aspx)** method as follows,

```
task.ContinueWith(oldTask => ProcessReturnedData(oldTask.Result));

// Example method
public IEnumerable<SomeEntity> ProcessReturnedData(DataSet data) { ... }
```

which will schedule calling the `ProcessReturnedData` method after the `task` object has done executing. Note that this will be called even if `task` fails for some reason, so it may not be always a good solution - or you would have to do some checks in the provided delegate.

If you want to do a non-blocking wait on the main thread and use the returned object there, you can simply use the **[`Wait`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235635.aspx)** method.

```
task.Wait(); // Makes current thread wait until the task is comnpleted.
DataSet result = task.Result; // Accessing the result object.
```

Comment: I am bound on some Windows XP machines so i cant go to the new functionality of .NET 4.5, so i think that i will stick to task class. Backgroundworker tends to be obsolete?

Comment: I think it is completely OK to use BackgroundWorker in Windows Forms app - it was designed as Windows Forms component. But I find Tasks more advanced in the way you can work with them, they're newer concept aimed at simplicity of usage, so if you can use them, I recommend it. BackgroundWorker is might be an option too, for example it supports reporting progress, so you can simply hook it to a progress bar and update it - but you didn't mention a need for this in your question and I think for a database action it doesn't make much sense anyway.

Comment: thanks but it wouldnt be more simpler if i just run something like: `var pi = Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(() => ComputePi(numDigits));
   ...
Console.WriteLine(pi.Result);` anf get the result directly to my ui? After all most of what i want to do is to run a method and get the database result back to my main thread.

Comment: Yes, that's a very simple case. You can see that with BGworker it would be a **[lot more](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)** work, maybe even more than with `Thread`

Comment: Nice, also tell me something if numdigits on the above example is a property of one window form control i get a "Cross-thread exception". I need more reading on delegates or something?

Comment: That's a thing with many GUI frameworks - you need to do UI changes (or changes to "Form" classes) on the GUI thread (usually the main thread). Your example creates a **[closure](http://www.codethinked.com/c-closures-explained)** on the `numDigits` variable, that may be a problem. Try passing it as an argument to the lambda, not directly to the ComputePi method: `Task.Factory.StartNew(num => ComputePi(num), numDigits);`

Comment: this was an example from MSDN, My live example is added to the question above.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20471/discussion-between-honza-brestan-and-e4rthdog)

Comment: Problem solved, will add it to the question for completeness. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I hade done a lot of projects using Thread, however Task should be more easy to use.

Here is demo how make async operations using Threads.

This is the class that will return data to ui:

```
public class MyAsyncClass
{

    public delegate void NotifyComplete(DataSet data);
    public event NotifyComplete NotifyCompleteEvent;

    //Starts async thread...
    public void Start()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(DoSomeJob));
        t.Start();
    }

    void DoSomeJob()
    {
        //just wait 5 sec for nothing special...
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        if (NotifyCompleteEvent != null)
        {
            //TODO: fill your data...
            DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();

            NotifyCompleteEvent(ds);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is ui implementation:

```
    MyAsyncClass myClass = null;


    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myClass = new MyAsyncClass();
        myClass.NotifyCompleteEvent += new MyAsyncClass.NotifyComplete(myClass_NotifyCompleteEvent);
        //here I start the job inside working class...
        myClass.Start();
    }

    //here my class is notified from working class when job is completed...
    delegate void myClassDelegate(DataSet data);
    void myClass_NotifyCompleteEvent(DataSet data)
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            Delegate d = new myClassDelegate(myClass_NotifyCompleteEvent);
            this.Invoke(d, new object[] { data });
        }
        else
        {
            //TODO: show your data
            MessageBox.Show("Data retrieved!");
        }
    }
```